# Creating INSERT trigger that sets values to 0

Tags: sql-server, triggers, dml

I have two tables : Invoice and Invoice_item, relationship 1 to many.
The Invoice_item table has columns Number_sold and Item_price, and the Invoice table has Number_sold_total and Item_price_total columns that will store total values of columns Number_sold and Item_price from the Invoice_item table with the same Invoice_ID key.

```
CREATE TABLE [Invoice] (
[Invoice_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Number_sold_total] [int] NOT NULL,
[Item_price_total] [decimal] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ([Invoice_ID]));

CREATE TABLE [Invoice_item] (
[Invoice_item_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Invoice_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Number_sold] [int] NOT NULL,
[Item_price] [decimal] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ([Invoice_item_ID],[Invoice_ID],
FOREIGN KEY ([Invoice_ID]) REFERENCES [Invoice]([Invoice_ID]);
```

So, if there are three rows in Invoice_item with the same Invoice_ID, the row with that Invoice_ID in Invoice table will have SUM values of corresponding columns in Invoice_item table.

Let's say i have three rows in Invoice_item table and columns Item_price with values 100,200 and 300, and they have the Invoice_ID = 3. The column Item_price_total in Invoice will have value of 600, where the Invoice_ID = 3.

QUESTION -
My task is to create an insert trigger on table Invoice that will set the values of Number_sold_total and Item_price_total to 0(ZERO) if there is no Invoice_item with corresponding Invoice_ID -> IF NOT EXISTS (Invoice.Invoice_ID = Invoice_item.Invoice_ID)...

I am using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: *"the row with that Invoice_ID in Invoice table will have SUM values of corresponding columns in Invoice_item table."* Ideally don't store aggregated values at all, use a `VIEW` and then you can just have a column where its value is defined by a `SUM`. Otherwise you need to update *any* relevant rows every time there are any DML statements; this can cause more problems that it solves.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Larnu. I know that is not the best and most optimal way to do it, but it is a task that needs to be done with triggers.

Comment: So why only a `INSERT` trigger? What about `DELETE`s and `UPDATE`s? Is the business happy to have "out of sync" data? What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? Why do you "need" to use a `TRIGGER`, when you know it's not the best way? *"Because the Business says so."* isn't a reason you "need" to; What the business "needs" and what is *actually needs* can be *very* different things; especially when those making the decision on what it "needs" aren't in a position to make informed decisions about the application/database design (which they normally aren't).

Comment: @Larnu, i created Update trigger, that will update those aggregated values, whenever Invoice_item is added. Also, created Delete trigger, and it works perfectly fine. 
This is for praciticing triggers with my mentor, so i have to use them.

Comment: OK, so you have created an `UPDATE`/`DELETE` trigger, so what isn't working for your `INSERT` one? Put your attempt in the question with an [edit], and explain what isn't working.

Comment: `[Item_price] [decimal]` Do you understand what the default values are for precision and scale when you do not supply them? It is generally a bad / lazy habit to not specify the attributes of datatypes that can vary. And be clear about your goal - an insert trigger for which table? or both? Your previous question involved a similar table structure and situation - seems like that is a good start. At the least you can write a stub of a trigger that does nothing.

Comment: @Larnu, the issue for me is that i don't know how exactly to check if there are no maching Invoice_ID values in Invoice and Invoice_Item table. The trigger logic after that would look something like my trigger that will insert TOTAL values upon creating Invoice_item rows. 

CREATE TRIGGER TR_Item_price_Insert ON Invoice_Item
......
UPDATE inv
SET Item_price_total = isNull(Item_price_total,0) + (SELECT SUM(Item_price) FROM
inserted 
WHERE Invoice_ID = inv.Invoice_ID)
FROM Invoice inv JOIN inserted i 
ON inv.Invoice_ID = i.Invoice_ID;

Comment: @SMor I have to create the trigger on Invoice table that will set TOTALs to 0 if there are no rows in Invoice_item table with the corresponding Invoice_ID. So, if an Invoice has no items, totals should be set to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you would not implement this using triggers.

Instead you should use a view. If you are worried about querying performance, you can index it, at the cost of insert and delete performance.

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.Invoice_Totals
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS

SELECT
  i.Invoice_ID,
  Number_sold = SUM(i.Number_sold),
  Item_price  = SUM(i.Item_price),
  ItemCount   = COUNT_BIG(*)  -- must include count for indexed view
FROM dbo.Invoice_item;
```

And then index it

```sql
CREAT UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_Invoice_Totals ON Invoice_Totals
  (Invoice_ID);
```

---

If you really, really want to do this using triggers, you can use the following

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TR_Invoice_Total
ON dbo.Invoice_item
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;  -- prevent spurious resultsets

IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted))
    RETURN;  -- early bail-out if no rows

UPDATE i
SET Number_sold_total += totals.Number_sold_total,
    Item_price_total  += totals.Item_price_total
FROM Invoice i
JOIN (
    SELECT
      Invoice_ID        = ISNULL(i.Invoice_ID, d.Invoice_ID),
      Number_sold_total = SUM(ISNULL(i.Number_sold, 0) - ISNULL(d.Number_sold, 0)),
      Item_price_total  = SUM(ISNULL(i.Item_price, 0) - ISNULL(d.Item_price, 0))
    FROM inserted i
    FULL JOIN deleted d ON d.Invoice_ID = i.Invoice_ID
    GROUP BY
      ISNULL(i.Invoice_ID, d.Invoice_ID)
) totals
ON totals.Invoice_Id = i.Invoice_ID;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cf06802e666423b09e179b2a576f8030)

The steps of the trigger are as follows:

- Bail out early if the modification affected 0 rows.
- Join the `inserted` and `deleted` tables together on the primary key. This needs to be a full-join, because in an `INSERT` there are no `deleted` and in a `DELETE` there are no `inserted` rows.
- Group up the changed rows by `Invoice_ID`, taking the sum of the differences.
- Join back to the `Invoice` table
- Update the `Invoice` table adding the total difference to each column.

This effectively recreates what the indexed view would do for you automatically.

You *cannot* just select the first row from `inserted` and `deleted` into variables, as there may be multiple rows affected. You must join and group them

Comment: Hello @Charlieface, thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work for me. Also, it's not clear for me what the trigger is doing. I am, lets say, still at beginner level. 
The trigger you created displays Incorrect syntax error at SET statements.

Comment: Hi, should be fixed now, and have added explanation

Comment: *"I am, lets say, still at beginner level."* Even more reason to use a `VIEW` then, @salesale . It's the *correct* solution and is far easier to use.

Comment: @Charlieface That works perfectly fine.  One more thing, can such trigger be created on Invoice table, and not on Invoice_item? Thank you!

Comment: @Larnu, i know, my mentor insists on doing it with triggers for practice. Thank you so much.

Comment: @salesale No because you want to pick up changes  to the `InvoiceItem` table, so you need a trigger on that.